# How is Spring's basePackages scan retrieving my classes from a different Maven module?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

I'm getting confused now with packages. It's broken down like this: Simple Maven multi module project. One parent POM, two sibling module children (one is a service module, one is a web module to be ran in Tomcat).

Below is my Spring Annotation Config for Dispatcher Servlet. Here is where I am confused. At first I didn't think basePackages was going to be able to scan for packages in a totally separate module (which is the service module). However, it somehow worked, exactly as written below. 'Entities' and 'Services' are the two packages from the Service module, while 'Controllers' comes from THIS web module. ***Let it be known*** that I have in fact added the Service module as a dependency into my web module. Nothing crazy going on there. Simple dependency so I can have access to my Service classes.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"entities", "services", "controllers"})
public class DispatcherConfig {

}
```

What I don't understand is how the packaging is working. It's all spaghetti'd in my mind now. When Spring gets to the line @ComponentScan and sees "entities", and "services", what is the structure it is looking on to get these classes?

My package structure is very simple. In the Service module I simply have src/main/java/entities ***and*** src/main/java/services

Something is happening behind the scenes here that I don't understand. How come Spring is smart enough to know this? I didn't even have to list the full package, i.e. myproject/src/main/java/entities or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: A bit out of date, but the principle is the same: https://nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/scott_leberknight/2008/06/just_how_does_spring_do_its_classpath_component_scanning_magic_

Comment: Your question seems to be how spring is able to "look into different maven modules". Well, maven modules are some synthetic thing for managing your projects. When it comes to a running Java application, all there is are classes and resources in your classpath. All Elements inside your classpath can be accessed in a number of ways (have a look at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner for example). Spring does all the scanning during runtime, so different maven modules just dont exists anymore from springs point of view.

Comment: `entities` *is* the package... There is no `src/main/java/entities` that is only your project structure. Just unpack the jar file deliver by the project and you will only see a `entities` package. Spring is just scanning the class path en all those packages are on the class path. For spring (or class loaders in general) there are no different packages/modules.

Comment: @samjaf Thank you all. I didn't realize that all it takes is for a class to be contained in a JAR within your final project build in order for Spring to be able to scan for it. I did not realize that packages in other modules were available to each other, but it makes sense now... As long as one module is a dependency of another, and its classes are accessible, everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

suppose @ComponentScan uses string array, like this:

```
@ComponentScan({"com.package.first","com.my.package.second"})
```

When you provide multiple package names in only one string, Spring interprets this as one package name.

This [post](http://bytescrolls.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-stuff-works-spring-component.html) might be helpful.